# Give user ability to reduce icon size on activity bar

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way for a user to reduce the icon size on the activity bar without it effecting the whole editor?

Perhaps similar to how Ubuntu allows the scaling of icons on the dock.

I use the activity bar and it's visual cues far to frequently to hide and unhide it, but it would be nice to reduce it's real-estate usage just a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS Code Editor press CTRL+-, this will increase/decrease the size of the entire UI (all icons, text and menu items, etc.).